# Ruby regex to match a pattern followed by another pattern

Tags: regex, ruby-2.1

I already have a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571937/936494) to match only single digits in a comma-delimited string. I need to update it to match the strings like following:

```
 5|5,4,3
 2|1,2 , 3
```

The constraints are

- it should start with a single digit in range of 1-5, followed by a pipe character (|)
- the string followed by the pipe character - it should be a single digit in range of 1-7, optionally followed by a comma. This pattern can be repetitive. For e.g. following strings are considered to be valid, after the pipe character:

  ```
  "6"

  "1,7"

  "1,2,3, 4,6"

  "1, 4,5,7"
  ```

However following strings are considered to be invalid

```
    "8"

    "8, 9,10"
```

I tried with following (a other variations)

```
  \A[1-5]\|[1-7](?=(,|[1-7]))*
```

but it doesn't work as expected. For e.g. for sample string

```
  5|5,4, 3, 10,5
```

it just matches

```
  5|5
```

I need to capture the digit before pipe character and all the matching digits followed by the pipe character. For e.g. in following sample string **5|5,4, 3, 2, 1** the regex should capture

1. 5
2. [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

**Note: I am using Ruby 2.2.1**

Also do you mind letting me know what mistake I made in my regex pattern which was not making it work as expected?

Thanks.

Comment: `/^[1-5]\|[1-7](\s*,\s*[1-7])*/`, perhaps?

Comment: you mean this `^([1-5])\|\s*([1-7]\s*(?:,\s*[1-7]\s*)*)$` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
^([1-5])\|([1-7]\s*(?:,\s*[1-7])*)$
```

**Example:**

```
> "5|5,4, 3, 2, 1".scan(/^([1-5])\|([1-7]\s*(?:,\s*[1-7])*)$/)
=> [["5", "5,4, 3, 2, 1"]]
```

**OR**

```
> "5|5,4, 3, 2, 1".scan(/([1-5])\|([1-7] ?(?:, ?[1-7])*)$/)
=> [["5", "5,4, 3, 2, 1"]]
```

Comment: is op wants to deal with a single space? then this `^([1-5])\|([1-7] ?(?:, ?[1-7])*)\b$`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regex that will match digits and a group of comma/space separated digits after a pipe:

```
^[1-5]\|(?:(?:[1-7]\s*,\s*)+\s*[1-7]?|[1-7])\b
```

Here is a [demo](http://rubular.com/r/kkNqbURDAs).

Comment: This will match `2|  ` and its because of that you putted the `\s` within character class!

Comment: @stribizhev add a space after pipe.

Comment: I have fixed the regex, now, it should work as expected.

Comment: This one matches: `^[1-5]\|(?:(?:[1-7]\s*,\s*)+\s*[1-7]?|[1-7])$`

Comment: No it will match `2|3,3 ,` ;) and `2,2,2`

Comment: I tested all those in the list: "6", "1,7", "1,2,3, 4,6", "1, 4,5,7". Working.

Comment: You need to test based on OP's condition!

Comment: Good try! i thinks now its the answer ;)